# find most common element in array and return new array

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to write a method: `static int[] moreCommon (int[] a)`

The method `moreCommon` accepts an `int` array as its sole argument and it returns an array of integers (with an appropriate length) containing all of the values having maximum frequency.

For example:

```
if a={1, 16, 10, 4, 16, 5, 16} it returns {16};    
if a={1, 16, 10, 1, 16, 1, 16} it returns {1,16};
if a=null it returns null;
if a={} it returns {}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: Questions asking for _homework help_ must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting started, I would suggest you start by thinking of how you can store an element alongside its frequency, then how to traverse a list and extract this information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to the exercise, though you probably can't use it, or even understand it, since it uses Java features you likely haven't learned yet, such as varargs, streams, and method references.

```
static int[] moreCommon(int... a) {
    if (a == null || a.length == 0)
        return a;
    return Arrays.stream(a).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            // here we have Map<Integer, Long> mapping value to frequency
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
            // here we have TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> mapping frequency to list of values
            .lastEntry().getValue().stream()
            // here we have Stream<Integer> streaming most frequent values
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sorted().toArray();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(moreCommon(1, 16, 10, 4, 16, 5, 16)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(moreCommon(1, 16, 10, 1, 16, 1, 16)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(moreCommon(null)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(moreCommon()));
```

*Output*

```
[16]
[1, 16]
null
[]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You were right, unfortunately I still can't understand this code.. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to offer you an answer according to your knowledge, according to samples the maximum number would be 16, the idea is to fill an array with 16 numbers 0, and we will work with the index, we will go through that array, in the first iteration the value of index will be 1, then for each iteration of that we will ask if in our array of numbers that value exists, if so we will add +1 to our array of 16 numbers with value 0, terms this process will have replaced the values ​​0 by the number of coincidences of your array numbers that match the index, 
you just have to finish coding it so that it returns the most repeated number, null or nothing. If it were necessary I could finish coding it but the important thing is that you understand the process and start playing with the loops, a greeting and anything you tell me.

```
public class main {

    static Integer [] numeros = {1,2,1,3,4,4};
    static Integer[] arr = Collections.nCopies(16, 0).toArray(new Integer[0]);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <arr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <numeros.length ; j++) {
                if(i<numeros.length){
                    if(numeros[j] == i){
                        arr[i]=arr[i]+1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <arr.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println("count of  numbers " + i + " :  "  + arr[i]);
                 }
             }
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
count of  numbers 1 :  2
count of  numbers 2 :  1
count of  numbers 3 :  1
count of  numbers 4 :  2
........
.....
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your time. However I'm not sure if that is what the program asks! The output should be and array containing all the most common numbers. For example ifa={ 1,2,1,3,2,5} it should return {1,2} which are the most frequent numbers